# Dealing with gaps in timeline

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I'm looking for some assistance to sort out the logic for how I am going to deal with gaps in a feed timeline, pretty much like what you would see in various Twitter clients. I am not creating a Twitter client, however, so it won't be specific to that API. I'm using our own API, so I can possibly make some changes to the API as well to accomodate for this.

I'm saving each feed item in Core Data. For persistance, I'd like to keep the feed items around. Let's say I fetch 50 feed items from my server. The next time the user launches the app, I do a request for the latest feed items and I am returned with 50 feed items and do a fetch to display the feed items in a table view.

Enough time may have passed between the two server requests that a time gap exists between the two sets of feed items.

```
50 new feed items (request 2)
----- gap ------
50 older feed items (request 1)
* end of items in core data - just load more *
```

I keep track of whether a gap exists by comparing the oldest timestamp for the feed items in `request 2` with the newest timestamp in set of feed items from `request 1`. If the oldest timestamp from `request 2` is greater then the newest timestamp from `request 1` I can assume that a gap exists and I should display a cell with a button to load 50 more. If the oldest timestamp from `request 2` is less than or equal to the newest timestamp from `request 1` the gap has been filled and there's no need to display the loader.

My first issue is the entire logic surrounding keeping track of whether or not to display the "Load more" cell. How would I know where to display this gap? Do I store it as the same `NSManagedObject entity` as my feed items with an extra bool + a timestamp that lies in between the two above and then change the UI accordingly? Would there be another, better solution here?

My second issue is related to multiple gaps:

```
50 new feed items 
----- gap ------
174 older feed items
----- gap ------
53 older feed items
* end of items in core data - just load more *
```

I suppose it would help in this case to go with an `NSManagedObject entity` so I can just do regular fetches in my Core Data and if they show up amongst the objects, then display them as loading cells and remove them accordingly (if gaps no longer exist between any sets of gaps).

I'd ultimately want to wipe the objects after a certain time has passed as the user probably wouldn't go back in time that long and if they do I can always fetch them from my server if needed.

Any experiences and advice anybody has with this subject is be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sadly I think the only way to work around this would be to *cleanly and carefully* implement check points throughout your table view delegates. Monitor where the user is in regards to the content, and at the appropriate times fetch for / insert content where needed.